# ios tableview last cell in table missing separator swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My table view's last cell was working fine and showing a separator. However when testing my app now I realized that the separator no longer comes up anymore for the last cell of the table. The only thing I can think of that might have caused this to happen was playing around with some of the preset tableview settings in main.storyboard.I checked but didn't notice anything different. Any one know what I might have changed to cause this, or now what to try to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: Is this on the emulator or a real device? Sometimes the scaling on the emulator causes things to appear differently than they would on a real iPhone.

Comment: its both on the emulator and the phone

Comment: Just to be clear, the separator for the last cell is missing at the top or at the bottom of the cell? Are you trying to set the table footer? This also can affect the bottom separator.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the last cell of a `tableView` does not show a separator. Someway to work around it include using a 1px `UIView` with background Color as separator.

The other way I prefer doing is to set a footer view. Something like this:

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

By setting a `tableFooterView` the last cell would show a separator.

Comment: i figured out my problem, my table was getting cut off so it looked like the separator disappeared. The problem i have now is that i am using self-sizing cells, and estimated row height. My tableview is a non scrollable table in a scrollview, so when i set my height using tableview.content size the tableviews height is off and isnt showing all of the cells.